# Apache serve default image when an image is missing

Tags: image, apache, mod-rewrite

We have several different size images for products.  We want to return the correct size default image whenever the product image is missing.

The path to the images are different for each product.
    path   /www/docroot/images/brand/product/product1_l.jpg
    path   /www/docroot/images/differentbrand/differentproduct/someotherproduct1_l.jpg
The size of the images look something like the items on the left.  We would want to chose the corresponding default image on the right.

```
product1_l.jpg large    noimage_l.jpg
product1_m.jpg medium   noimage_m.jpg
product1_s.jpg small    noimage_s.jpg
```

I have seen some examples of people achieving something similar using mod_rewrite.  Can anyone give any guidance on how I can use that to fit my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You need an intelligent 404 handler.  If Apache throws a 404 (File not found) error the intelligent handler should try to salvage the event by looking at the pattern of the URL, and locating a known resource to serve instead.  You should also handle the possibility that the fall back image might also not be there.

This page can show you how to check if a file is present, but the logic will need to be in the last line.

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/5

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Or you can go the .htaccess route (I think that's cleaner)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Assuming you could use .htaccess and PHP here is one solution:

Add this line to your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Then add this code to you error.php like this

```
<?php
 if(preg_match("/^/images/thumbnail/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
   //do a 302 redirect
   header( 'Location: /images/defualtImage.jpg' ) ;
 } else {
   //You need to go somewhere to handle actual 404 errors
   header( 'Location: /static/404.html' ) ;
 }
?>
```

[302 redirect directs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) would work best here.

Comment: I am running java.  PHP is not available to me.  It looks like I would need conditional rewrites to achieve different default images for different sizes.  Is that possible?

Comment: As in tomcat or Jetty? As for images of different sizes as long as this name has some clue about the intended size for example: a file path like /thumbs/(product)-(size).jpg could be inelegantly rewritten as /thumbs/default-(size).jpg

Comment: Apache/Tomcat 
I am not good with regex could you steer me in the right direction or point me to a good resource where I can get up to speed quickly.   
Below are three examples of images requests that we may get.   

www.imgdomain.com/images/nike/airjordan/32513_black_l.jpg     rewrite to /images/noimg_l.jpg
www.imgdomain.com/images/nike/airjordan/32513_black_m.jpg     rewrite to /images/noimg_m.jpg
www.imgdomain.com/images/addidas/kobe/34923_yellow_m.jpg   rewrite to /images/noimg_m.jpg

Comment: I would take a look at URLRewriter for Tomcat.  It will let you define  a rewrite rule like ^/images/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\d]+)_([\w]).jpg then you can route any request that matches this pattern to a server like /imageLoader?brand=$1&subbrand=$2&id=$3&size=$4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments. We ended up going with a different solution. We used the onerror js tag to point to the appropriate noimg location. This was cleaner and easier for our environment